# Is there a way to connect pymongo to a local file without using mongodb?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I want to use `pymongo`'s syntax to query a local json file.  Currently I'm using a mongodb instance to handle the information in the file, but I was wondering if there's a way that doesn't require to have a running mongodb instance and allows me to have pymongo query capabilities (`find`, `distinct`, etc).

I searched the documentation and `MongoClient` doesn't seem to support that requirement.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, [mongoquery](https://pypi.org/project/mongoquery/) has this capability.